# eMac G4 Recovery Mode with Windows Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, recovery, emacs

I recently acquired an eMac G4, but I did not get an Apple keyboard with it. I need to restore it to factory settings, but cannot access recovery mode with my Windows keyboard. I've tried Alt+R, Ctrl+R, and Start+R, but nothing. Is there any way to access recovery mode with a windows keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

OS X Recovery was introduced with [OS X Lion](https://www.macworld.com/article/1161088/mac-apps/hands-on-lion-recovery-mode.html). [At best, your eMac supports 10.5.8 Leopard.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMac) If you want to install from scratch, you'll need either the original install disks or a system installation disk.

You can bring another bootable OS X drive that runs a supported OS for that hardware and get to things like terminal / Disk Utility as well but this hardware pre-dates recovery on the firmware / OS level.